# Create new array using items from current array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this....

```
Array
(
    [result] => Success
    [finals] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 633
                    [name] => RESULT84
                )
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 766
                    [name] => RESULT2
                )
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22
                    [name] => RESULT1
                )
        )
)
```

Using PHP, I am trying to create another array from it that only contains the [name] field.

Do I need to create a new array from this or is there a way to use it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`array_columm()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), assuming your array is in a variable called `$data`:

```
$names = array_column($data['finals'], 'name');

print_r($names);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => RESULT84
    [1] => RESULT2
    [2] => RESULT1
)
```

`array_column()` is available from PHP version 5.5.0.

You may also use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$names = array_map(function ($final) {
    return $final['name'];
}, $data['finals']);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If you need the name in a signle array you can declare a new array `$array =[];` and  the use the array_push global function within a foreach and do `array_push($array, $value['name']);`